# Materials not showing in object mode or render view

Tags: rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, edit-mode, object-mode

For some reason, my materials only show up in edit mode, but not in render view. It WAS working before, but I have no idea what I did to mess it up. I can't seem to find a solution that works after over an hour of searching.

[image]

[image: Object mode]

[image: Edit mode]

[image: Rendered view]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site! Could you please add some screenshots so we can see what's going on? (Some people either don't want to or just can't download .blends, for example if they're on mobile.)

Comment: Added screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Your eye is made of two spheres, one with the iris and pupil textures and a second that surrounds the first which I expect you plan to put a transparent texture that also adds the part in front of the iris.

This second sphere has no texture yet, which is why it hides the inner sphere when rendering. Also you have hidden the vertices for this outer sphere in edit mode which allows you to see the inner sphere in edit mode.

Press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> while in edit mode to unhide the vertices, you can then select the outer sphere and assign a transparent texture to finish your eye.

Comment: I must have accidentally duplicated something at some point. Thanks!